# Convert har file or fiddler export to smart jmx

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I was just wondering if there is a way of generating a smart jmx* (*blazemeter recorder provides this*) from a `.har` or `.saz` (*fiddler archive*). **Please do not provide alternate solutions.** I just want to know if blazemeter or any other services provide a way to generate auto-correlated script from `.har` or `.saz` files.

*smart jmx is an auto correlated jmeter script provided by blazemeter proxy recorder. [Read more here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter).

[image: blazemeter create script]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten about this question. I ended up writing a tool which parses `.saz` file and spits out a jmeter script (`.jmx` file). You can [find it here, its called saz2jmx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saz2jmx). Although its not exactly what I wanted (doesn't have the auto correlation feature) but it has the potential to be made one! People interested to contribute are welcome! I will write about it soon.

cheers.

Comment: accepting this answer for now as it is the most relevant but happy to change it if something else comes up.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) there are no standalone solutions, you will need to **replay** your `.har` or `.saz` file via the BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder in order to get it auto-correlated.

With regards to Fiddler, it should be able to [replay the requests](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Generate-Traffic/Tasks/ResendRequest) out of the box:

[image: Fiddler replay]

For standalone .har files it might be more tricky as you will have to install i.e. [har-replay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/har-replay) utility and configure it to use your file.

In both cases requests **must be replayed via the proxy**.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri for the answer. Let me wait for couple of days if anyone has any other answers.

Comment: Replaying the traffic via the blazemeter proxy require the application to be available online which is not the case with my app.